# Next js run different env variables

Tags: javascript, next.js, environment-variables

I am using NextJS. I need to create 3 type of environments:

1. development
2. staging
3. production

I need to run on each env. specific variables. 
 For development i have `.env`, for productiuon i have `.env.production` and for staging i have `.env.staging`. My scrips looks like this:

```js
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
},
```

For simulating staging env. i created this:

```js
"start:staging": "NODE_ENV=staging next dev -p 3001",
```

But when i check `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV, 'env variable');` i get `development`. 
 What i do wrong and how to get the proper variables?

Comment: Internally, Next.js will override the `NODE_ENV` environment variable automatically based on the command you run (`next dev` or `next start`). I'd recommend you use a different, custom environment variable to set the type of environment you need.

Answer (score 1):

You are running `next dev` wich makes your application runs with developmento mode, thats why you get `development`.

Take a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development

If you whant to use next.js build in env features you have the follow their docs https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables.Basically you can have 3 environment files, local, development and production and they will be used when running the application with next dev and next start. The local env files always overrides the others, do not commit it to your project or your dev and production files wont be used.

If you want to do the exactly thing you said (development, staging and production) you will have to override next env by yourself. You can achieve this using dotenv.

One of my projects utilizes this configuration: https://github.com/RizziSilva/task-time-web. The crucial files can be found in the environment directory, next.config.js and server/dotenv.js. It's important to note that this project is of a personal nature and may not precisely align with your specific requirements.

Comment: Can you please share a link or example of using `dotenv` in order to have custom environments?

Comment: I edit the my answer with a link to one of me personal projects that use this config.